# Sum up data from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, sum

I have some JSON data to sum but I get an error. This is my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
{
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
    int Total = 0;
    try
    {
        pesanan = json.getJSONArray("pesanan");
        for (int i = 0; i < pesanan.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject ar = pesanan.getJSONObject(i);
            Total = ar.getInt("Total");
            Jumlah = Jumlah + Total;
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Totalbayar.setText(Jumlah);
```

**My Php **

```
     <?php
      $kd = $_GET['meja'];
      include("koneksi.php");
      $q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_pesanan where Id_meja ="'.$kd.'"');
      $v = '{"pesanan" : [';
      while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
     {
        $ob = array();
        $v .= '{"Total" : "'.str_replace($ob,' ',strip_tags($r["Total"])).'",}';


      $v .= ']}';
       echo $v;
       ?>
        }
```

JSON data:

```
{"pesanan" : [{"Total" : "20000"},{"Total" : "10000"},{"Total" : "27000"}]}
```

Logcat:

07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3428)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at aplikasi.slluberscafe.TungguPesanan$tampil.onPostExecute(TungguPesanan.java:95)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at aplikasi.slluberscafe.TungguPesanan$tampil.onPostExecute(TungguPesanan.java:1)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    07-08 08:25:50.487: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I want to sum up the variable `Total`.

Comment: JSON expects commas between each element of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json array `[{"Total" : "20000"}{"Total" : "10000"}{"Total" : "27000"}]` must be seperated by a comma `,`

**UPDATE:**

`<?php
      $kd = $_GET['meja'];
      include("koneksi.php");
      $q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_pesanan where Id_meja ="'.$kd.'"');

      //My update
      $output['pesanan'] = array();
      while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
      {
        array_push($output['pesanan'], array('Total' => $r['Total']));
      }
      echo json_encode($output);
?>`

**UPDATE 2**
This update for resource error. You're setting the `Integer` value for `Text`. So compiler will looking for the text in `string.xml` which have Id match with your `Jumlah` value. So you must convert `Jumlah` to String:
`Totalbayar.setText(String.valueOf(Jumlah));`

Comment: how to fix? "Total","20000" ?

Comment: You must fix this in your PHP code to return something like this:
`{"pesanan" : [{"Total" : "20000"}, {"Total" : "10000"}, {"Total" : "27000"}]}`

Comment: not work, my php fix like {"pesanan" : [{"Total" : "27000"},{"Total" : "7000"},]}

Comment: Remove the last comma or put your PHP code here

Comment: @user3806892 can you fix my php? see above

Comment: nothing has changed, output php {"pesanan" : [{"Total" : "27000"}{"Total" : "7000"}]}

Comment: Sorry, this work
`$ob['pesanan'] = array();
 while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    array_push($ob['pesanan'], array('Total' => $r['Total']));
}
return $ob['pesanan'];`

Comment: can you write full php? pleas, output not appear

Comment: Please see my update above

Comment: error, logcat update pleas see above

Comment: Did you test my PHP code? What result did return?

Comment: php : [{"Total":"27000"},{"Total":"7000"}]

logcat : 07-08 10:39:33.674: E/JSON Parser(534): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Total":"27000"},{"Total":"7000"},{"Total":"7000"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Ok. see my update code, in the last line, edit with this: `echo json_encode($output);`

Comment: fix php, but error program, 07-08 10:58:01.954: E/AndroidRuntime(750): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa604

Comment: You done on Json error, and now getting resource error, the problem in the line `Totalbayar.setText(Jumlah);`. You are setting `Text` with the `Integer` value, its mean you're setting a String Id for this and Android will looking for a text on `strings.xml` which match with this `Id`, but not found. You must use `Totalbayar.setText(String.valueOf(Jumlah));` to fix it.